# Combining IN, KEEP, DROP, and RENAME statements

Tags: sas

How does one combine multiple KEEP, DROP and RENAME statements, particularly while combining this with IN statements? As an example, it seems like the following should be possible with only a single DATA step:

```
data temp;
  set set_1 (keep = key var1-var5);
  run;
data want;
  merge set_2
        temp (in= whatwewant);
  by key;
  if whatwewant;
  run;
```

How would I do this with only a single data step?

Also, a similar question: how does one combine, for instance, a KEEP and a RENAME statement in a data step? I've run into several instances recently where I want to merge on some set of variables that have different names in two different sets, yet I only want to keep a proper subset of the variables from either set. In this case, based on my knowledge, I actually need three data steps to accomplish this when I assume it could be done in a single step. I've been doing something like this:

```
data temp1 (rename = (key1=key));
  set set_1 (keep= key1 var1-var5);
  run;
data temp2 (rename = (key2=key));
  set set_2 (keep=key2 othervar1-othervar4);
  run;
data want;
  merge temp1
        temp2;
  by key;
  run;
```

So, same question: how might I do this in a single data step?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can put an IN, KEEP, DROP, or RENAME in the same options block inside the same parentheses.

In your first case:

```
data want;
  merge set_2
        set_1 (in= whatwewant keep = key var1-var5);
  by key;
  if whatwewant;
run;
```

In your second case:

```
data want;
  merge set_1 (keep= key1 var1-var5 rename = (key1=key))
        set_2 (keep= key2 othervar1-othervar4 rename = (key2=key));
  by key;
run;
```

Comment: Thank you! I've been trying to figure out the syntax for this for awhile now, and couldn't figure out how to search for this. I apparently I didn't try this!

Comment: Search for "SAS data set options"

Comment: Thanks, both of you. This was very helpful!